# How to transform a binary tree into a heap in place?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, heap

I have thought of the following:

1. Degenerate the tree into a linked list, and while degenerating, make
   a dynamic array with the node object and its index in the linked
   list

It would look like this

> ```
> def treeDegenerator(self):
>     self.valList = []
>     currentNode = self
>     self.totalNodes = 0 
>     self.nodes = 0
>     while currentNode:
>         while currentNode.getLeftChild():
>             currentNode.rotate_root_right()
>         self.valList.append(currentNode)
>         currentNode = currentNode.getRightChild()
>         self.totalNodes += 1
> ```

2. use the dynamic array, dereference all left childs and right childs and transform the degenerated tree into a complete tree by
   using (index value)*2+1 to get the left child, add 1 more for the right.

> ```
> def completeTree():
>     for node in self.valList:
>         node.left = None
>         node.right = None
>         
>     for i in range(len(self.valList)):
>         self.valList[i].left = self.valList[(i)*2+1]
>         self.valList[i].right = a.valList[(i)*2+2]
> ```

3. Turn into heap by shifting values by comparison of the children for each node, level by level,starting at the bottom.

This was a problem for which students had to code without any references on a past exam. The issue with my method is that, its pretty much impossible for me to write all that code down in 30 minutes properly, and maybe could be possible if i memorize some code before hand. I was wondering if theres an easier, more feasible and elegant solution to turn any binary tree into a heap in place?

Comment: Do you need the resulting tree to be a conventional binary heap (all layers filled in from left to right), or just to have the heap property (each node is smaller (or bigger than) its children)? Also, are you allowed to swap values between nodes, or is the only permitted operation to rewire pointers? Finally, any bounds on the expected time complexity?

Comment: It's hard to see what "in place" means when the input is a tree of linked nodes and the output is a heap-ordered array.

Comment: @templatetypedef no bounds, yes it must be a conventional binary heap. The values to be swapped can be done, so long as its coded for

Comment: @MattTimmermans No, the output is still a tree of linked nodes. I have added some code for step 2 which may have caused a misunderstanding

Comment: Ah, IC.  I still don't think using O(n) extra space for the list counts as in-place.  I've provided an answer that uses O(log n) stack, which counts as in-place for sorting so I guess it works here, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually you can break this task down into two steps:

1. Rebuild the tree into a perfectly-balanced BST with the bottom row filled in from left-to-right. You can do this using a modified version of the [Day-Stout-Warren algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day%E2%80%93Stout%E2%80%93Warren_algorithm).
2. Run the [heapify algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) to convert your tree into a binary heap. This can be done really beautifully recursively; see below for details.

The Day-Stout-Warren algorithm works by rotating the tree into a singly-linked list, then from there applying a series of rotations to turn it into a perfectly-balanced tree. I don't remember off the top of my head whether the DSW algorithm specifically will place all leftover nodes in the bottom layer of the tree on the far left, as needed by a binary heap. If not, you can fix this up by doing a cleanup pass: if the tree doesn't have a number of nodes that's a perfect power of two, remove all nodes from the bottom layer of the tree, then iterate over the tree with an inorder traversal to place them on the far left.

As for the heapify algorithm: the way this is typically done is by visiting the layers of the tree from the bottom toward the top. For each node, you repeatedly swap that node down with its smaller child until it's smaller than all its children. With an explicit tree structure, this can be done with an elegant recursive strategy:

- If the tree has no children, stop.
- Otherwise, recursively heapify the left and right subtrees, then perform a "bubble-down" pass of repeatedly swapping the root's value with its smaller child's value until it's in the right place.

This overall requires O(n) time and uses only O(log n) auxiliary storage space, which is the space you'd need for the stack frames to implement the two algorithms.

<editorializing> That being said - this seems like a really bad coding question to put on a 30-minute timed exam. You can have a great command of algorithms and how to code them up and yet not remember all the steps involved in the two substeps here. Asking for this in half an hour is essentially testing "have you memorized implementations of various unrelated algorithms in great detail?," which doesn't seem like a good goal. </editorializing>

Comment: agreed, i was also thinking of using the daystout warren algo. thats where the tree degenerator in my code came from, but i figured coding the rotations needed to make it into a perfectly balanced tree would be quite difficult to remember hence why i thought of using the pointers of the array and just using the 2 * index property would be better off to get a complete tree.  That being said, do you think that this question cant be solved without degenerating the tree? I really cant think of any possible solution without doing this step.

Comment: @HarshDua I don’t know a more direct way to turn the tree into a perfectly balanced one, but there very well might be one.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would first collapse the tree into an ordered linked list on node.right.
2. I'm assuming we started with an ordered BST. If not, then sort the list.  If you want a max-heap instead of a min-heap, then reverse the list at this point, too.
3. Count the nodes and calculate the depth of the largest complete tree contained in the solution
4. Do a recursive preorder traversal of the complete tree, filling in each node from the head of the list as you go.
5. Do a pre-order traversal of the tree you just built, filling in leaves from list nodes until you run out

Step 4 would be accomplished recursively like this:

```
root = list
fillChildren(root, list.right, levels-1)


fillChildren(root, list, levels) {
    if (levels < 1) {
        root.left = root.right = null
        return list
    }
    root.left = list
    list = fillChildren(root.left, list.right, levels-1)
    root.right = list
    list = fillChildren(root.right, list.right, levels-1)
    return list
}
```

The trick to this, of course, is that mapping nodes in order to a pre-order traversal satisfies the heap property.

It's also pretty easy to combine steps 4 and 5 just by keeping track of each node's index in an imaginary array heap.

Just for fun, here's the whole job:

```
treeToHeap(root) {

    if (root == null) {
        return null
    }

    // Convert tree to list

    while(root.left != null) {
        root = rotateRight(root)
    }
    for (n = root; n.right != null; n=n.right) {
        while (n.right.left != null) {
            n.right = rotateRight(n.right)
        }
    }

    // Count nodes
    count = 0
    for (n = root; n!=null; n=n.right) {
        count+=1
    }

    // Build min-heap
    
    list = root.right
    // root's index in imaginary array heap is 0
    
    if (count>1) {
        root.left = list
        list = fillNodes(root.left, list.right, 1, count)
    } else {
        root.left = null
    }
    if (count>2) {
        root.right = list
        list = fillNodes(root.right, list.right, 2, count)
    } else {
        root.right = null
    }
    return root
}

fillNodes(root, list, heapIndex, heapSize) {
    heapIndex = heapIndex*2+1
    if (heapIndex < heapSize) {
        root.left = list
        list = fillNodes(root.left, list.right, heapIndex, heapSize)
    } else {
        root.left = null
    }
    heapIndex += 1
    if (heapIndex < heapSize) {
        root.right = list
        list = fillNodes(root.right, list.right, heapIndex, heapSize)
    } else {
        root.right = null
    }
    return list
}
```

So that took 15 minutes (and I didn't bother to write out rotateRight), and that's *after* figuring out how to do it.  And I returned a couple times to fix bugs.

For a 30 minute exam, it's quite tough...  BUT maybe the exam didn't really require the heap to be perfectly balanced.  If it's just a question of implementing an in-place heapify, then it's quite reasonable.

Comment: Unfortunately its not a bst, but yeah.